# Why I can't use the unit test method definied into this unit test class?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I am pretty new in C# and I have the following situation.

I have a **Unit Test** class named **UnitTest1** into a project named **UnitTestProject**.

In this class I have the following method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ConnectionMaliciousCodeManager()
    {
        DataModel.MaliciousCodeManager manager = new DataModel.MaliciousCodeManager("DefaultConnection");

        try
        {
            manager.openConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            manager.closeConnection();
        }
    }
```

and it work well.

Now I am doing some refactoring and I have create a new **MaliciousUnitTest** class into my project and I want to moove the previous method into this new class but now it don't work. This is my entire **MaliciousUnitTest** class code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    class MaliciousUnitTest
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void ConnectionMaliciousCodeManager()
        {
            DataModel.MaliciousCodeManager manager = new DataModel.MaliciousCodeManager("DefaultConnection");

            try
            {
                manager.openConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                manager.closeConnection();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have no errors but the problem is that when I put the mouse cursor on my **ConnectionMaliciousCodeManager()** method and if I try to do right click and click on **Run Tests** nothing happens.

If I go into the Visual Studio **Text Explorer** section I can't find the **ConnectionMaliciousCodeManager()**.

Why? What am I missing? What have I to do to use the test methods that I define into my new **MaliciousUnitTest** class?

Tnx

Comment: Does the test class need to be `public` (rather than `internal`, the default visibility)?  This appears to be MSTest rather than NUnit.  If so, please adjust the tags.

Comment: Patrick i bet that is it. Write it down as an answer

Comment: @PatrickQuirk if you write it down I will sign as accepted :-)

Comment: It was just a guess, but that's great if it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the test class have `public` visibility.  Not specifying the visibility means your test class is `internal`, which Visual Studio is unable to see.

Comment: +1 If that's a guess it's a very good one. This is definitely the case.